# Postgres query won't finish in function but if run separately it works

Tags: postgresql, function, sql-execution-plan

This is simplified version of my function with the query in it (therefore any variables are now useless) and this function won't finished but if I run the same query separately it finishes in under a second.

function that never finishes

```
select * from test_function_difference(1);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function_difference ( 
  p_does_nothing int

)  
RETURNS TABLE(
  t_datum date,
  t_capacity numeric,
  t_used numeric,
  t_category int,
  t_category_name text,  
  t_used_p numeric,
  t_unused_p numeric
)
  VOLATILE
AS $dbvis$

declare
p_sql text := '';
p_execute text := '';
rec record;
begin

p_sql := 
'
 with 
vytizeni as (
  select 
    date_trunc(''day'',mcz.datum)::date as datum ,  
    sum(zd.v_vytizeni)/3600.0 used
  from v_ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace mcz
  left join (select * , pul_den as den_noc from v_ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace_zdrobneni) zd on mcz.id = zd.id
  where
    datum between  ''2018-12-31'' and ''2018-12-31''

    and ( zahranicni = 0 or zahranicni is null )
     and den_noc = -1 
  group by 
    date_trunc(''day'',mcz.datum)::date
)
,kapacita as (
  select
    date_trunc(''day'',datum)::date as datum , 
    sum(obsazeni_g)/3600.0 capacity
  from v_ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace
  where
    datum between  ''2018-12-31'' and ''2018-12-31''

  group by
    date_trunc(''day'',datum)::date 
)
,zdroj as (
  select 
    k.datum,  
    k.capacity,
    v.used,
    -1 category
  from kapacita k 
  join vytizeni v on k.datum = v.datum
)

select
  c.* , 
  kc.nazev::text categeroy_name,
  case when sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) = 0 then 1 else used/sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) end as used_p,
  greatest(1 - case when sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) = 0 then 1 else sum(used)over(partition by datum)/sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) end,0) as unused_p
from  zdroj  c
left join v_ui_cdc_s5_kategorie_cinnosti kc on kc.id = c.category
order by c.datum
';

raise notice '% ' , p_sql;

RETURN QUERY 
execute p_sql;

END;
$dbvis$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and the query I run separately (finished in 533 ms)

```
with 
vytizeni as (
  select 
    date_trunc('day',mcz.datum)::date as datum ,  
    sum(zd.v_vytizeni)/3600.0 used
  from v_ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace mcz
  left join (select * , pul_den as den_noc from v_ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace_zdrobneni) zd on mcz.id = zd.id
  where
    datum between  '2018-12-31' and '2018-12-31'

    and ( zahranicni = 0 or zahranicni is null )
     and den_noc = -1 
  group by 
    date_trunc('day',mcz.datum)::date
)
,kapacita as (
  select
    date_trunc('day',datum)::date as datum , 
    sum(obsazeni_g)/3600.0 capacity
  from v_ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace
  where
    datum between  '2018-12-31' and '2018-12-31'

  group by
    date_trunc('day',datum)::date 
)
,zdroj as (
  select 
    k.datum,  
    k.capacity,
    v.used,
    -1 category
  from kapacita k 
  join vytizeni v on k.datum = v.datum
)

select
  c.* , 
  kc.nazev::text categeroy_name,
  case when sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) = 0 then 1 else used/sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) end as used_p,
  greatest(1 - case when sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) = 0 then 1 else sum(used)over(partition by datum)/sum(capacity)over(partition by datum) end,0) as unused_p
from  zdroj  c
left join v_ui_cdc_s5_kategorie_cinnosti kc on kc.id = c.category
order by c.datum
```

Edit: I was able to get results from the function after almost 28 minutes (also I tried it on Sunday night, means I had the resources of the whole server, because during normal load function have not finished even after one hour) and right after that I ran query standalone and get results after 2.1 sec Here are the explain analyze

function: 28 minutes
https://explain.depesz.com/s/v9xJ

standalone query: 2.1 sec
https://explain.depesz.com/s/aBri

second run stand alone 430ms
https://explain.depesz.com/s/ENva

Interesting note: if I edit start date for the interval to '2018-12-30' or any other date the function finishes as well

which means

```
start date = '2018-12-31'
query => finishes under 1 second
function => won't finish
start date = '2018-12-30'
query => finishes under 1 second
function => finishes under 1 second
```

Version details: PostgreSQL 10.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

Comment: From the execution plans you originally posted, it vas clear that the estimates for the number of rows was much higher with `2018-12-30`. Give it some time - if you can produce `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, it will be easier to analyze the problem.

Comment: I can give you explain analyze for the query run separately  but I can't do it for the function since it doesn't finish (I stopped it after 45 minutes of running)

Comment: explain analyse if query run separately https://explain.depesz.com/s/Zji6

Comment: Then the plain `EXPLAIN` for the long running query will be enough. Please put that stuff into the question, not a comment.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe do you know if there is a system table with stored plans that was actually executed for the question, I am bit suspicious that the execution plan I gave you earlier may not be correct since it look exactly the same as the of from separate query, I just put into the function 'EXPLAIN VERBOSE ' and stored to variable and printed

Comment: because otherwise the plan would look like this
'Function Scan on reports.test_function_difference  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=168)'
'  Output: t_datum, t_capacity, t_used, t_category, t_category_name, t_used_p, t_unused_p'
'  Function Call: test_function_difference('2018-12-31'::date)'

Comment: You would put `auto_explain` in `shared_preload_libraries` and restart the server. Set `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` and `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0` and run the function. Then you will get the execution plan in the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: thank you, I will try to do it, but I have to get permission for restarting our server so it may take me some time to provide the log

Comment: If you are a superuser, you can also simply `LOAD auto_explain`, then `SET` the parameters for the session and run the function. You can get the log to the screen with `SET client_min_messages = log`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I did it but unfortunately it was not any helpful
1) log does not appear until query finishes
2) format is useful only for queries out of function 
this is how the log looks for the function, I set startdate to '2018-12-30' for it to finish
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_function_difference(date) line 69 at RAISE
LOG:  duration: 1107.359 ms  plan:
Query Text: select * from test_function_difference('2018-12-30')
Function Scan on test_function_difference  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=168) (actual time=1107.327..1107.328 rows=2 loops=1)
Total query runtime: 1.1 secs

Comment: I used this manual
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/auto-explain.html

Comment: Yes, there is no log entry unless the function finishes. Also, as I said, you need `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` to get plans from inside a function. One thing you can try is adding an `EXPLAIN` to the dynamic query *inside* the function so it returns the plan rather than the result.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry I have missed the part with auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on now it's working, but with function not finishing it is still not any help, I tried to put explain analyse and explain verbose into the function earlier but verbose gave me exactly the same plan as if I run query outside of the function, and I put analyse before execute in the function and analyse finished under one second but then function itself was not finishing, therefor I said I am suspicious that this way gives me wrong plans

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe finally after 28 minutes the function finished, I will edit my question and put results there

Comment: I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference in the performance is that the execution inside the function does not use parallel queries, and parallel execution by chance picks a better execution plan.

Is the function not marked as parallel safe? That may make all the difference.

The core problem, however, is the gross mies-estimate of the number of result rows for the scan on `ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace`, which estimates 1 instead of 2243 rows.

You should `ANALYZE` that table to get a better estimate. If that alone doesn't improve the estimate, try to raise `default_statistics_target` before the `ANALYZE`.

If you need to raise `default_statistics_target` for a better estimate, persist that change with

```
ALTER TABLE ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace
   ALTER datum SET STATISTICS <whatever proved useful>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the analysis
1)function was exactly as I provided in topic, I tried it to modify it as parallel safe, but I found only a very little in documentation about it, I put `PARALLEL SAFE` behind `VOLATILE` in my function which compiler accepted but it made no difference for running the function(log showed no parallel use and function was also not finishing), therefore I am not sure whether I used parallel safe correctly
2) as for the analyse I will try to do it if parallel safe won't help

Comment: You did the right thing. Not sure if it makes a difference.